# Exception Handling in Python for continuous execution

Tags: python, exception

The question is related to Python:

Normally, I use except(RuntimeError) and use continue, so my code does not break while processing huge amounts of data.

However, it is harder for me to include all the types of errors that I encounter while running my code, since there are multiple possibilities. How do I just say - whatever happens - don't break but just continue, instead of including (RuntimeError, TypeError, ValueError and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using only except with no parameters?

```
try:

 code

except:

 continue
```